# Using Permutation Test to check the correlation of two random variables

Tags: hypothesis-testing, bootstrap, permutation-test

Assume we observe in paris $(x_i,y_i)_{i=1}^n$. For example,

```
X: 45,23,37,89
Y: 13,78,23,13
```

Here we maintain the assumption that $(x_i,y_i)_{i=1}^n$ are i.i.d. samples from the joint distribution of $P_{X,Y}$. Now we want to test whether $X$ and $Y$ are uncorrelated, which is much weaker than the claim of independence.

We have two ways of doing that:

1 Bootstrap. My example with $n=4$ is kind of too small, let's pretend here $n$ is large. Then one could do sample with replacement from the set of pairs $(x_i,y_i)_{i=1}^n$ and generate $n$ pairs, then repeat this procedure for $B$ (large) times. In each iteration, one could compute the empirical correlation and after $B$ iterations, one will get a distribution of the empirical correlation, denoted by $\hat{F}_\rho$. Note that the logic for the bootstrap is that the original sample $(x_i,y_i)_{i=1}^n$ is representative of $P_{X,Y}$ and hence every bootstrap sample generated from $(x_i,y_i)_{i=1}^n$ is also a representative of $P_{X,Y}$. Hence, based in $\hat{F}_\rho$, one could construct confidence interval (for the true correlation $\rho_{X,Y}$) and check if 0 is inside the confidence interval. If 0 is not in the CI, then we reject the null and conclude that the correlation of $X,Y$ is not zero with significance leve $\alpha$.

The logic of bootstrap procedure is pretty straightforward. Now let's look at another method, the permutation test. Here I copy the procedure, since I don't quite understand its logic for testing the correlation of two random variables. I do understand its logic for testing the mean difference of the treatment group and control group.

2 Permutation Test. The procedure is that: we fix the order of the entris in $X$, e.g., $45,23,37,89$ is fixed, then in each iteration, we generate a random permutation of $Y$, e.g., in iteration 1, we have Sample 1

```
X: 45,23,37,89
Y: 78,13,23,13
```

In iteration 2, we have Sample 2

```
X: 45,23,37,89
Y: 13,78,13,23
```

In this small example, we could go through all the permutations of $Y$, then in each permutation we compute the empirical correlation and after all the iterations, we can get a distribution of this empirical correlation (under $H_0$. Note that in the bootrap, that distribution is not under the null but the true distribution), then we can check how extreme (i.e., the $p$ value) of observing the empirical correlation in the original sample.

My question is the following: I believe for the permutation test, the $H_0$ is $\rho_{XY}=0$. This is much weaker than $X,Y$ being independent. Then, based on the $H_0$, the above proposed procedure looks to me that it claims the probability of observing Sample 1 and Sample 2 are the same. However, one can show that only if $X,Y$ are independent, then one can conclude that the probability of observing Sample 1 and Sample 2 are the same, i.e., uncorrelated is not enough. From here, because of this question, I missed the logic of permutation test for the correlation of 2 random variables.

Note that in the traditional context of applying permutation test, the $H_0$ is usually very vague, i.e., the observation of a score is independent of the treatment. Therefore, based on that, we can permutate the observed score from treatment group and control group and do the permutation test. However, in testing the correlation between 2 random variables, we have a very specific $H_0:\rho_{XY}=0$. I understand that by construction (the proposed procedure), the constructed empirical distribution of the correlation (under $H_0$) will have mean zero. However, it still does not solve my puzzle. My question is what is the logic of the proposed procedure for the permutation test in this case (for testing the correlation of 2 random variables)? I think the proposed procedure makes sense only if the $H_0$ is $X,Y$ are independent (rather than just uncorrelated)

I learned this based on this set of notes, which I think is very good 
https://www.uvm.edu/~dhowell/StatPages/Randomization%20Tests/RandomizationTestsOverview.html

Comment: What then is your question? What is the puzzle?

Comment: @MichaelChernick My question is what is the logic of the proposed procedure for the permutation test in this case (for testing the correlation of 2 random variables) I think the proposed procedure makes sense only if the $H_0$ is $X,Y$ are independent (rather than just uncorrelated)

Comment: In the bootstrap you didn't assume independence. The pairs could be independent but not necessarily y independent of x.  Permutation tests assume exchangeability which is not the same as independence either.

Comment: @MichaelChernick will the $H_0: \rho_{X,Y}=0$ implies exchangeability? Or exchangeability is a maintained assumption? And what does exchangeability mean in this specific example? I don't understand the relationship between exchangeability and the $H_0$

Comment: When you don't assume a specific parametric model, the hypothesis "$X$ and $Y$ are uncorrelated" is not testable because it does not imply any specific sampling distribution for any statistic.

Comment: @whuber So you mean in this permutation test for testing the correlation of 2 random variables, the $H_0$ is actually "X and Y are independent"? And then we implement the proposed procedure and obtain the empirical distribution of the estimates of correlation. Then if we found the p-value of the observed correlation comparing to the reference distribution under $H_0$ is too small, then we say $\rho_{X,Y}\neq 0$, which also implies that $X$ and $Y$ are dependent. Is that correct?

Comment: In *any* permutation test, the null is that the variables are exchangeable.  See Phillip Good, *Permutation, Parametric, and Bootstrap Tests of Hypotheses* (Third Edition), section 2.2, *Basic Assumptions.*